# How to get Column Foreign Key Constraint using SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net

How can we get foreign key constraint using `SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` method?

My code:

```
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

Dim dt As DataTable = dataReader.GetSchemaTable()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849701/how-to-get-columns-primary-key-constraints-using-sqlconnection-getschema) answers how to check the primary key. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks